# Facebook Graph API - get Posts in PHP

Tags: php, facebook, performance, facebook-graph-api, posts

Im trying to get posts from a Facebook page.
I did that in [here](http://www.thundervector.pt/proposta/test.php)
The problem is that the page is a little bit slow (4 or 5 seconds to load)

I am using 2 "foreach" to get the data and maybe thats the problem.

---

Here is my code:

```
$json_object = @file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$page_id.'/posts?limit=4&access_token=' . $access_token);

$fbdata = json_decode($json_object);

foreach ($fbdata->data as $post)
{
$postid = $post->id;

    $json_object2 = @file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$postid.'/attachments?access_token=' . $access_token);

    $fbdata2 = json_decode($json_object2);

    foreach ($fbdata2->data as $post2)
    {
        $title = $post2->title;
        $type = $post2->type;
        $url = $post2->url;
        $desc = $post2->description;
        $desc = str_replace("\n", "<br>", $desc);
        if (strlen($desc) > 200){
           $desc = substr($desc, 0, 200) . '...<br>...<br><a href="'.$url.'" target="_blank">Ver mais</a>';
        }

        $imgsrc = $post2->media->image->src;
        if ($type=="note") {
            ?>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <a href="<?php echo $url;?>" target="_blank"><div class="img" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $imgsrc; ?>');"></div></a>
                <a href="<?php echo $url;?>" target="_blank"><h1><?php echo $title; ?></h1></a>
                <p><?php echo $desc; ?></p>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
    }
}
```

---

Im not showing you the *"page_id"* and *"access_token"* variables but they are correct.

What can I do to get a better performance in the page load?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, of course it is slow if you fire a number of API requests inside a loop. Use field expansion instead, to request all that data in one go. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#fieldexpansion

Comment: Thank you! I am using Graph API fields like this:
    `"https://graph.facebook.com/".$page_id."/?fields=posts.limit(4){id,message,attachments{title,type,url,description,media{image{src}}}}&access_token=" . $access_token`
and then just read it like an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course it is slow if you fire a number of API requests inside a loop.
(The most slowing part is the HTTP request your app makes to talk to Facebook’s servers – and if you make single API requests in a loop, that means one HTTP request for each one of them.)

Use field expansion instead, to request all that data in one go: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#fieldexpansion